# Excel VBA code that pause randomly, but eventually finishes. How do I determine where the pause is happening?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large chunk of Excel VBA code that cycles through a group of cells performing a whole series of operations.  It pauses for a long period of time (2 min+-) randomly, or at least in a pattern I cannot detect.  The code will finish eventually without throwing a error.  I know this pause is happening because the cell receiving the end data is selected, centering it in the view of the sheet.  I can visually see that it is temporarily hanging, but not sure where in the code it is happening?  Any ideas on how to find out where this long pause is occurring?  Outside of totally refactoring the code and checking function completion times, I would appreciate any ideas how to come at this to locate the hang point.  One of the factors are up to six different workbooks being accessed for data (yes I know, use a database....legacy issues).

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/5925/switch-off-properties-during-macro-execution#t=201701312253281756566) will also help speed up your code.  Make sure you try the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: It probably isn't hanging - it's probably just not handed control back to Windows for a while and therefore Windows has stopped allowing screen updates.  (I notice that sort of thing when I include a `Application.StatusBar = "..."` in my code and forget to include a `DoEvents` after it - the status bar updates happily for a while, then stops, and then the code finally finishes and all is right with the world again.)

Comment: `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` is used in the code.  This allows me to track the progress as it updates the cells it is cycling through.  The code, as best as I can tell, should take only about two minutes to complete.  This is based  on how quickly it goes through the first couple hundred cells.  With the pause, it takes about 6-7 minutes to finish.  I tried posting updates to the status bar in different places.  But it always seemed to hang at a different location.

Comment: Sometimes, but not always, I get the white blanked out '(Not Responding)' screen.

Comment: (a) If you have `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` then your screen shouldn't be updating and you shouldn't be able to see the updates to the cells it is cycling through.  (b) Try putting some `DoEvents` statements in your code (e.g. after your status bar updates) and see if the problem still occurs.